# read jpeg2000 files in java

Tags: java, jpeg2000

I have a code using a `byte[]` that contains a image jpeg2000 bytes. I want show this in `jLabel` component howto do this? Anyone have idea or code to do?

Answer (score 4):

You would do it in this way

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);

JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon);
```

but the **JPG2000** decoder isn't supplied with standard SDK, you should head [here](https://jai.dev.java.net/) (Java Advanced Imaging) and use the right decoder for that format..

Comment: I've downloaded the jai (from the java site, not from your link, because i can't find the jai file to download it) but, when i tried to use your way to read the image. I got the Null exception, i don't know why. even that i did add the jar files to my project(reference them).. so, what the solution for that ??

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the support of jpeg2000 / ( .jp2 ) files has been removed from Java Advanced Imaging (JAI).

By un-installing JAI 1.1.3 and installing the older version 1.1, I'm now about to read .jp2 files and no longer see the null pointer.

Version 1.1 is available here.
http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/

Version 1.1 lists codec's for - g3fax g4fac jiio jp2k jpeg and png

Comment: Link is dead, here is a new link to the oracle archive http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html

Comment: Man this image format is a pain in the back

Answer (score 2):

The only options I know are all based on jj2000.

**jai-imageio-core** provides support through an additional third-party module:

https://github.com/stain/jai-imageio-core

https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000

It'll register itself with ImageIO and you'll then be able to read jpeg2000 files as you would any png, bmp or jpeg.

Although jj2000 is in itself an option, the api is not designed for day-to-day use.

Other options include [JMRTD](http://jmrtd.org/), which provides its own wrapping for jj2000, 
or a commercial offering, [JDeli](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jdeli).

Comment: There is now another option (based on jj2000), from BFO: https://github.com/faceless2/jpeg2000

Answer (score 1):

With the Java library [imageio-openjpeg](https://github.com/dbmdz/imageio-jnr) (Apache 2 license) you can use Jpeg2000 files (*.jp2) with the imageio API from Java. It is based on [OpenJPEG](https://www.openjpeg.org/) (BSD license). Since 2015 is OpenJPEG the reference software of the Jpeg2000 standard.

If you want use it then you need both imageio-openjpeg and the OpenJPEG for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best project I could find until this day that supports JPEG2000/J2K images:

It also provides good documentation to use:

https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000