# writing Jpeg 2000 images in java

Tags: java, image, jpeg2000

I am trying to encode (write) jpeg 2000 in Java. I am reading a '.bmp' image and try to write '.jp2' image. I am using:

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img1, "jpeg 2000", file1);
```

I do not receive any error, but the size of the produced image is zero. Can anybody help me please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information. What is img1? Is it valid? What is file1? Is it valid? ...

Comment: img1 is a BufferedImage, file1 is declared as: new File("E/a.jp2");  they are valid, because if I try to write the image as a 'bmp', 'jpg' or 'png' file, everything is fine.

Comment: @Shadi ok it should work then, sorry that I cant help you.

Comment: check the links http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5318325 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662916/read-jpeg2000-files-in-java. These might help.

Comment: Thanks Emil, I had checked them before, they could not have helped me. BTW, than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem was that when I was installing JAI_ImageIO, I should have selected "custome installation" and checked everything to be installed. Thanks everyone.