# How to include jpeg2000 compression standard in code?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-compression, jpeg2000

I am new to JAVA. I am working on Image compressions. How can I compress .jpg images with jpeg2000 in JAVA. Does java has any library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back I had to read a jpeg2000 file. What I found was the older version of Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) supported jpeg2000, but the later ones didn't.

Version 1.1 is available here. http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/

Link to my post. 
[read jpeg2000 files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662916/read-jpeg2000-files-in-java/13167748#13167748)