# How to read a jp2 image into BufferedImage in java

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg2000

I want to read a jp2 image into BufferedImage in java. I installed the Java Advanced Imaging JAI. This is my code:

```
RenderedOp img = JAI.create("FileLoad",  "/home/dhoha/Downloads/BreastCancer.jp2");
  BufferedImage image =  img.getAsBufferedImage();
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getColorModel(RenderedOp.java:2242)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2498)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2546)
    at testJai.test.main(test.java:19)
```

I cannot understand why the JAI library is not able to read the jp2 images although this operation is feasible with the bmp images..

Any hint please???

Comment: Which version of JAI you have? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167748/1737819

Comment: Yes I have intalled the older version of JAI 1.1 because the JAI 1.3 does not support the jpeg 2000 images... and currently I'm facing this problem. Any hints?

Comment: Do import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ImageWriter
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()));
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()));
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes()));
 }
} does it list jp2 as a filetype?

Comment: yes, jp2 it's there.

Any hints?

Comment: Unfortunately, no hints...