# How to display a jpeg2000 image on a Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jpeg2000

I have a jpeg2000 image, `img.jp2` on a file, and on a DataInputStream object `imgobj` in my project, and want to show that image on a JFrame.

The old version  [jai_imageio-1.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jai/jai_imageio-1.1.jar.zip) recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167748/3408531) and the [jj2000](https://github.com/stain/jai-imageio-core) library are both included.

I have tried:

```
    j2kImageReader.setInput(new FileImageInputStream(new File(fileName)));
            ImageReadParam imageReadParam = 
j2kImageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
imageReadParam.setSourceRegion(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300));
IIOImage image = j2kImageReader.readAll(0, imageReadParam); 

       // This type of images is difficult to handle, 
       // I just don't know what to do with IIOImage, 
       // ImageIcon doesn't accept that type in its constructor.
```

And this:

```
    Image img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);

JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon);
panel1.add(label);
panel1.repaint();

//Error: Can't read input file!. The panel is still empty
```

The option included in JMRTD is using two decoders, and no one of them accepts `.jp2`:

```
NistDecoder dec=new NistDecoder();
WsqDecoder wdec=new WsqDecoder();

//using the last one, I tried: bitmp= wdec.decode(myDataInputStream);
//but with Error, Invalid pointer : 0!.
```

So the question is: what is the proper use of jj2000 or jai_imageio to read a jpeg2000 image from a file or a DataInputStream, and if it is possible, to show it on a simple panel on a JFrame?

Thank you for help.

**EDIT**

AS requested in comments, this is what I did:

```
         //1   
         FaceImageInfo imgfn = fsinf.getFaceImageInfos().get(0);
         BufferedImage bf=ImageIO.read(imgfn.getImageInputStream());

         ImageIcon iconImg = new ImageIcon();             
         iconImg= new ImageIcon(bf);// if this fails try write it to a stream and read it back see //2
         JLabel(iconImg, JLabel.CENTER);


         //2
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos=null;
         try{
             baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ImageIO.write(bf, "jpg", baos);
         }
         finally{
             try{
                 baos.close();
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         try {
             ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
             bf2=ImageIO.read(bais) ;
             iconImg= new ImageIcon(bf2);
             JLabel(iconImg, JLabel.CENTER);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: ...and what happened, *exactly*, when you tried the above?

Comment: I have explained in the code, thank you @haraldK.

Comment: Hi. please share with me your solution. What maven or jar file did you use?

Comment: @AliHoseinpour See the edit, I hope it helps you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code otherwise reads the image like you want it, you can easily get a `BufferedImage` from the `ImageReader` like this:

```
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(fileName))) {
    j2kImageReader.setInput(input));

    // Not sure why/if you want to read only the upper left, but I'll leave it as is
    ImageReadParam imageReadParam = j2kImageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
    imageReadParam.setSourceRegion(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300)); 

    // Use read instead of readAll
    BufferedImage image = j2kImageReader.read(0, imageReadParam); 

    // You can now create an icon and add to a component
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    // Etc...
}
```